# Дек на основе однонаправленного цикличного списка

Tags: c++, list, список, очередь, односвязный-список

Столкнулась с проблемой (а точнее заданием с университета): создать дек на основе однонаправленного цикличного списка. И, собственно, я не смогла найти никакой информации по поводу данного условия; максимум, что я находила, это деки на основе массивов (через вручную расписанные функции или `#include <deque>`, что мне использовать не стоило бы, как и классы).
Хотелось бы узнать, как все-таки реализовать данный дек.  Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Полное условие выглядит так:

- Элемент структуры: вещественное число.
- Дек на основе циклического однонаправленного списка.
- Используя только основные операции для дека после каждого парного,
  вставить элемент со значением 0.

Примерное объявление списка и его инициализация:

```
struct list
{
    double field;
    struct list* ptr;
};
struct list* init(double a)
{
    struct list* lst;
    lst = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    lst->field = a;
    lst->ptr = lst;
    return(lst);
}
```

Comment: собственно, ваша задача - реализовать "однонаправленного цикличного списка" с операциями вставки и удаления в начало и конец. Вот и дек получится.

Comment: Наверное, требуется вставка в начало, и удаление из конца (или наоборот). Не представляю, как сделать удаление с обоих концов O(1), на однонаправленном списке.

Comment: Сначала напишите циклический однонаправленный список, представьте его в вопросе. В таком случаи легче будет отвечать. Не то придется все написать за вас

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, мне не столько код нужен, как алгоритм, что к чему и как и зачем 

Comment: @hyen, по вопросу это понятно. Но вы же все равно пытались сначала написать список. Как он реализован, от этого ответить станет легче.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, добавила

Comment: ОК, я так и думал_ сначала пишите правильный однонаправленный циклический список , чтобы каждый элемент указывал на следующий, а последний  на первый. Нужно сначала  осилить это, а потом спрашивать как на его основе сделать еще что то. И уточните метку . Может С++ вам вообще не нужен...

Comment: hyen я помню - вы уже писали список в другом задании и он даже работал. :) Сейчас вы написали структуру для 1 элемента списка, а не для списка. Когда у Вас будет циклический список, то операции добавления/удаления в начало и в конец очереди это одна и та же операция, только указатель на начало или конец списка нужно переприсвоить. И если вы не хотите использовать классы, то действительно не нужно на вопрос ставить метку С++.